# refresh parent from child window?

Tags: css

im trying to create a star rating system, i just need to focus on the css part of it at the moment.

it fills the stars as the user hovers over with the mouse, but it does it right to left and i want to make it work left to right.

Can someone show me what i'd need to change to do this. thanks.

```
<span class="rating">
    <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
        id="rating-input-1-5" name="rating-input-1">
    <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
        id="rating-input-1-4" name="rating-input-1">
    <label for="rating-input-1-4" class="rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
        id="rating-input-1-3" name="rating-input-1">
    <label for="rating-input-1-3" class="rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
        id="rating-input-1-2" name="rating-input-1">
    <label for="rating-input-1-2" class="rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
        id="rating-input-1-1" name="rating-input-1">
    <label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>
</span>
```

css:

```
<

    style>
    .rating {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .rating-input {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -50px;
    }
    .rating-star {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background: url('assets/img/icons/stars.png') 0 0px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: 22px 20px;
    }
    .rating-star:hover {
        background-position: 0 16;
        background: url('assets/img/icons/favorites.png') 0 0px;
        background-size: 22px 20px;
    }
    .rating-star:hover,
    .rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star,
    .rating-input:checked ~ .rating-star {
        background-position: 0 0;
        background: url('assets/img/icons/favorites.png') 0 0px;
        background-size: 22px 20px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: Just reverse the order of your HTML, 5 should be at the end, not the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

Simply inverse the star order (in your mark-up too):

```
.rating-star {
  float:right;
  margin-right: 5px; 
}
```